# change git history to include modified code

Tags: git, version-control

Imagine I have the following git history:

```
a ----- b ----- c
               HEAD
```

where HEAD is at c.

Now I found a bug in (a) which obviously is now in (b) and (c) too. What I now want to do is change code(repair the bug) in (a) and want to update the same in (b) and (c) too. How should I do this with git?

Thanks

Comment: It may be best to fix the code and create a new (d) commit with that fix vs rewriting history depending on the type of bug.

Comment: But, if I want to do testing on my master branch, I will have to manually edit the code everytime I checkout (b) or (c)

Comment: For what you want to checkout to old commits?

Comment: I may be losing performance on my further commits because of the modification, so I might just want to check what performance my old commits gave. There could be many reasons to checkout old commits, I just listed one..

Comment: @mc_87 What you describe is abusing version control terribly. Just don't do it. Git doesn't allow you to arbitrarily rewrite history so you can base your workflow around it; but mostly because it refuses to take a philosophical stand against it. Many VCSes explicitly refuse to let you do what you describe, and it's for very very good reasons. It's perfectly okay for old commits to have bugs that are fixed later, that's why they're old.

Comment: @mc_87 Also, what do you mean by "losing performance because of the modification"? If you rewrite history to change `a` in a way that hurts performance, then obviously `b` and `c` will perform worse as well. It just doesn't make sense; if you rewrite history, that actually means you **can't** check out the old commits anymore, because they're replaced by entirely different ones with the change you've added to `a` spliced in.

Comment: @millimoose while it is somewhat "abusive" to VC to do this, I think sometimes there is legitimate cause. What if you're working locally on some feature you wish to later submit for review to some one else (perhaps a maintainer). It does make sense to want to submit the most concise and clear set of changes, so that the history reflects exactly what you were trying to do. Fixing the bug in the original commit allows you to do so, and as long as you didn't push it yet, no harm is done to anyone.

Comment: @millimoose I agree with your reasoning.. even I dont want to rewrite history.. but I have good reasons for checking out older checkouts to do performance benchmarking.. I need to understand what workflow with git I should follow so that I am able to solve my problem and also do it in a sane way with git.

Comment: @avivr That's what patch queue managements tools are for. Or bug trackers that associate commits with issues. "Present a concise set of changes" is the mentality that leads SVN users to the antipattern of not making a commit for days. I don't think this is something that should be handled at the VCS level, it comes across more as OCD than a legitimate need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your question it seems that you want the history to look like there was never a bug.
You could do something like this:

- Fix the bug in a new, regular commit. We'll call it commit `d`.
- Use interactive rebase: `git rebase -i <hash-of-commit-before-a>`.
  In the editor window that appears, you'll see the commits a, b, c, d each on a new line, with a command (`pick`) in front of them.
- Re-order the lines so that the line with the new commit is right after the line representing commit `a` (should be second line).
- Change the command infront of the new commit to `squash` (instead of `pick` which is the default).
  This will cause your new commit, `d`, to be merged into the first commit, `a`.

Note that if you pushed these commits to another repo, rebasing is a bad idea. In a nutshell, this is because you're actually creating new commits (with new hashes), not just re-ordering existing ones. If someone else pulled your code and based work on the original commits, when he pulls again he'll have duplicates and he will have to manually fix this.
See [The perils of rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing#The-Perils-of-Rebasing) for a better explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3

#An editor window will now open showing 3 commits. Replace 'pick' with 'e', save exit.
#git will now give you a chance to edit last 3 commits. Edit the files to fix the bug, then

git add -u
git commit -m"New message"
git rebase --continue

#This will repeat 3 times. After that, you will have a new set of last 3 commits (with new sha1 of course).
```

BTW after this point you will not be able to do a 'push' if your 3 commits are already in the remote (origin). You will have to do a:

```
git push -f
```

This will also prevent anyone else to pull in case they have old commits. But that can be solved when others do this:

```
git stash # save your changes.
git reset --hard HEAD~3
git pull
git stash pop
```

Comment: Mind you, my solution were I one of the "others" would be to throw a shoe at whoever caused the situation.